# Is there any "nice" representation for algebraic numbers of degree 3 (or higher)?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Every decimal number have a finite decimal expansion !

Every rational number has its decimal expansion becomes periodic after some digits.

Every rational number has a finite continued fraction representation.

Now every algebraic number of degree 2 has a periodic continued fraction representation
after some digits.

Is there another representation of numbers such that an algebraic number of degree 3
or more is  periodic after some digits?

Comment: This is an old open problem posed by Hermite. Search on the "Jacobi-Perron algorithm" to locate literature on this and closely related topics, e.g. [see this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.12707)

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal number"?  Do you mean integer?

Comment: @badjohn: Probably means decimal fraction (fraction with denominator $10^k$ for some $k$; similarly "dyadic fraction" means denominator is $2^k$).